# How to escape template syntax in templates

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am making a page in my Play app that talks about how to make Play app pages. (Very meta :P)

I couldn't find anything in the Play Framework documentation that explains how to escape Play's template syntax in a template. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you use the Groovy templates or the Scala templates? Are you using Java or Scala?

Comment: if you are using groovy, then #{verbatim} tag escape everything inside it

Comment: I'm using Groovy templates, but #{verbatim} doesn't escape template tags/expressions.

Comment: I am not sure its possible. Can you explain your use case as there may be a workaround.

Comment: The use case is I'm making a "look and feel" page to show my team members how to use the custom tags and styles in our app, with working examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say you want to display `${name}` as HTML text and not let play render a value for variable name then the answer to the question can be found when letting play compile ${"$"} in the template.

Play produces an error stating:

```
 illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"
```

This actually means that if you want to display `${name}` you should write the following

```
${"\${name}"}
```

Try this, it works!

Comment: Yep, that is the more correct answer than the one I posted myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution but if you replace the $ in any of your tags with the ascii escaped equivalent then it works, eg, if I want to print ${user.name} out on the screen then the text I would enter would be:

```
&#36;{user.name}
```

Obviously the same goes for any other special characters that the templating language uses as a trigger eg #, @ and %

Comment: Yes, that works. It's a shame that it's necessary, but you're right -- this appears to be the only solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Came up with an interesting solution for this:

```
${"#{a @Controller.action()}${user.name}#{/a}"}
```

Play automatically escapes the contents of the string to HTML entities. This ultimately requires less extra code, and as a bonus it means I can copy & paste template code as-is into the page.

I hope this is helpful to someone. :)